# Build failed on heroku for Angular CoreUI template

Tags: angular, heroku, core-ui

I am not able to deploy my angular 8 project. I have used CodeUI angular template and build is getting failed on Heroku deployment. The same thing is working on localhost but not able to make a build on Heroku.

The versions I am using:

- Angular CLI: 8.3.6
- Node: 10.16.0
- Angular: 8.2.8

Getting below error:

```
Build
Detected both "build" and "heroku-postbuild" scripts
Running heroku-postbuild

HireCommit@2.5.2 heroku-postbuild /tmp/build_434f7be8a26abfc4235d95846f4eafd0
g build --aot --prod


Date: 2020-02-10T11:18:59.393Z
Hash: 753b3b69ed4e240fe2ea
Time: 52490ms
chunk {0} runtime.741402d1d47331ce975c.js (runtime) 1.41 kB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {1} main.4af9b61479361f268d39.js (main) 128 bytes [initial] [rendered]
ERROR in node_modules/@coreui/angular/lib/sidebar/app-sidebar.component.d.ts(13,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
node_modules/@coreui/angular/lib/sidebar/app-sidebar.component.d.ts(14,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
node_modules/@coreui/angular/lib/sidebar/app-sidebar-nav/app-sidebar-nav-items.component.d.ts(11,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
node_modules/@coreui/angular/lib/sidebar/app-sidebar-nav/app-sidebar-nav-items.component.d.ts(12,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
node_modules/@coreui/angular/lib/sidebar/app-sidebar-nav/app-sidebar-nav-link.component.d.ts(15,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
node_modules/@coreui/angular/lib/sidebar/app-sidebar-nav/app-sidebar-nav-link.component.d.ts(16,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
       chunk {2} polyfills.d64fff5b0a45205ed7b5.js (polyfills) 130 bytes [initial] [rendered]
       chunk {3} polyfills-es5.7f9896f05667ed1b2b2b.js (polyfills-es5) 68.1 kB [initial] [rendered]
       chunk {4} styles.f9d3d53855388a7c759d.css (styles) 578 kB [initial] [rendered]
       chunk {scripts} scripts.b59d910a7125cd182ed3.js (scripts) 471 kB [entry] [rendered]
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! HireCommit@2.5.2 heroku-postbuild: `ng build --aot --prod`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the HireCommit@2.5.2 heroku-postbuild script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /tmp/npmcache.u9GWJ/_logs/2020-02-10T11_18_59_473Z-debug.log

Build failed



           We're sorry this build is failing! You can troubleshoot common issues here:
           https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys

           If you're stuck, please submit a ticket so we can help:
           https://help.heroku.com/

           Love,
           Heroku

     !     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app.
     !     Push failed
```

You can find my package.json [here](http://clientapp.narola.online/HD/test/package.json)

Comment: is it possible for you to update to Angular 9? it has been released less than a week ago and should fix your issue

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 1):

@coreui/angular v2.9.0 uses Angular 9 and TypeScript 3.7

*TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context*

You've got typescript v3.4.5 in your dependencies and you are affected by this issue. TypeScript 3.7 emits get/set accessors in .d.ts files. It can cause breaking changes for older versions of TypeScript like 3.5 and prior.
- TypeScript 3.6 was future-proofed for this feature.
- See: [Class Field Mitigations](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#class-field-mitigations)

1. update your project to Angular 9 https://update.angular.io/ and TypeScript to 3.6 / 3.7
2. the other option is to lock @coreui/angular dependency on version 2.5.5 / 2.6.3
3. or update @coreui/angular to 2.9.1

**@coreui/angular v2.9.1** uses Angular 9 and **TypeScript 3.6** - Angular 8 compatible

Answer (score 0):

I have got similar issue in **Bitbucket** (not in Heroku ). In my case, i've two options..
First one is to update Angular Project and Ts. But not possible for my case.
Second one is to update core UI. That work for me .
edit Package.json file as

```
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^8.0.0-rc.2",

     "@angular/router": "^8.0.0-rc.2",

-    "@coreui/angular": "^2.4.5", // remove

+    "@coreui/angular": "2.5.3", // add

     "@coreui/coreui": "^2.1.9",
```